# Core Graphics function/C why does the called function populate the sent array?

Tags: c, function, pointers, core-graphics

Apologies for what, I assume, is a rather ignorant, newbie question.

```
CGDirectDisplayID displays[10];
uint32_t numDisplays;

CGGetOnlineDisplayList(10, displays, &numDisplays);
```

The above function populates the displays[] array and returns a result (the number of online displays) to numDisplays. The definition in header is as follows:

```
CG_EXTERN CGError CGGetOnlineDisplayList(uint32_t maxDisplays,
CGDirectDisplayID *onlineDisplays, uint32_t *displayCount)
CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_2, __IPHONE_NA);
```

I understand why we use '&numDisplays': we are giving the function the address of the variable so that it can change it directly. But why don't we use the same operand with the array? Shouldn't we handle it in the same way we handle numDisplays? How does the function manage to populate the array when we are not passing its address to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the function manage to populate the array when we are not passing its address to the function?

We are.

When passing an array to a function, it's not the contents of the array that is passed. Instead, a pointer to the first element of the array is passed; we say that the **array decays into a pointer.** As you can see from the prototype of the function anyway.

If you passed `&arr`, that would technically be the same pointer, but it would be of another type (it would be a pointer-to-array, `uint32_t (*)[10]`), but passing a pointer-to-array when a pointer-to-(type of an element of the array) is required is invalid. Don't use `&`.

Comment: To add, this is why the function "GCGetOnlineDisplayList" requires you to tell it how many elements the array contains (i.e., 10 in this case). It is only aware of the starting address of the array and nothing else. It uses the first parameter to determine the size.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays *decay* to pointers to their first element.

So `&display[0];` is equal to `displays;`